# Starting loops with python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, functional-programming

So we just started learning about loops and got this assignment

`def    factorial_cap(num):` For    positive    integer n,  the factorial   of  n   (denoted    as  n!),    is  the product 
of  all positive    integers    from    1   to  n   inclusive.      Implement   the function    that    returns the smallest
positive    n   such    that    n!  is  greater than    or  equal   to  argument    num.

Examples:

`factorial_cap(20)` → 4 #3!<20 but 4!>20

`factorial_cap(24)` → 4 #4!=24

Can anyone give me a direction as to where to start? I am quite lost at how to even begin to start this. I fully understand what my program should do, just not how to start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is to keep dividing the argument by [1...n]. When the number becomes smaller than the divisor, the divisor is the answer.

```
20/1=20;
20/2=10;
10/3=3.33<4--------------4

30/1=30;
30/2=15;
15/3=5;
5/4=1.25<5---------------5

90/1=90;
90/2=45;
45/3=15;
15/4=3.75<5--------------5

900/2=450;
450/3=150;
150/4=37.5;
37.5/5=7.5;
7.5/6=1.25<7-------------7
```

The function should be like this:

```
def factorial_cap(num):
    c=1
    while(c<num):
        num=num/float(c)
        c=c+1
    return c
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am not a python guy, so gave you the logic.

Comment: please mark the answer if it helped - so it helps future visitors as well ;). thx

Answer (score 0):

In a recursive function there are two main components:

1. The recursive call
2. The base case

The recursive call is when you call the function from within itself, and the base case is where the function returns/stops calling itself.

For your recursive call, you want n*factorial(n-1), because this is essentially the definition of a factorial (n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*2). Following this logic, the base case should be when n == 2.

Good luck, hope I was able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way is calculate the factorial of each integer starting from 1 (or 0) until the factorial of a number be greater than or equal to `num`.

```
def factorial_cap(num):
    number = 0
    factorial = 1
    while(factorial < num):
        number += 1
        factorial = factorial * number
    return number
```

Start with `number = 0`, we know that 0! is 1, so `factorial = 1`.
With a while loop calculate the factorial of the next number multiplying the previous factorial by the new number (`n! = (n - 1)! * n`) until this be greater than or equal to `num`, and finally return the number.